# How to enable email alert from VPC Flow Logs for threat detection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

We have enabled VPC Flow logs for our ALL VPC's, now I am searching for creating Alert to detect the Malicious activity and send mail when it detects.

What is the process to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use CloudWatch and Amazon SNS notifications.

Another good service is AWS Config, which will check your configuration and its changes.

See: [Publish flow logs to CloudWatch Logs - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs-cwl.html)